# VS2010 Professional SP1 reports correct _MSC_FULL_VER for 32-bit compiler but non-SP1 _MSC_FULL_VER for 64-bit compiler

Tags: 64-bit, visual-studio-2010

When building a 32-bit application, _MSC_FULL_VER correctly equals 160040219, but when building x64, _MSC_FULL_VER is set to 160030319. The order I had installed stuff, due to needs over the years, is:

- installed VS2010 but without the 64-bit compiler/tools
- installed SP1
- also installed various hotfixes/etc.
- (some years later) installed the 64-bit compiler/tools
- saw that the 64-bit compilation of an application was reporting the incorrect (i.e. non-SP1) _MSC_FULL_VER
- re-ran the SP1 install to re-apply SP1
- SP1 re-apply successfully completes
- despite that, _MSC_FULL_VER is still incorrect for 64-bit compilation as if SP1 wasn't applied at all

I was going to remove SP1 to re-install, but the remove warns that the post-remove state could be such that it's not possible to re-install SP1.

What do I need to do to fix this problem so that 64-bit building is in a proper SP1 state (and _MSC_FULL_VER is reporting the correct value)?

Comment: Are you *positive* that the x64 compiler version should be different (e.g. by checking another machine)? It's possible that the 32-but and 64-bit compiler version numbers aren't kept exactly in sync.

Comment: I assume they should be in sync based on code that is causing me a problem: `#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER == 1600 && _MSC_FULL_VER < 160040219) // etc.` - this is from a header file that's used in building 64-bit applications. That `#if` should test false since there's a big fat `#error` right after warning of why the `.h`/`.lib` needs SP1 installed.